# Can a Linux script be run from stored procedure in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, bash, shell

I want to run a shell script from a stored procedure as a workaround to achieve functionality not offered by tool by default.

Is it possible? Database is SQL Server, bash shell

Answer (score 1):

Nope the approved answer is totally wrong. At the moment even with SQL Server 2022 xp_cmdshell isn't usable with the linux version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2022?view=sql-server-ver15#unsupported-features-and-services

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. To use xp_cmdshell you have to activate it, this is done with the commands:

```
-- this turns on advanced options and is needed to configure xp_cmdshell
sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
RECONFIGURE
-- this enables xp_cmdshell
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1' 
RECONFIGURE
```

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment the xp_cmdshell and all related filesystem feature are reserved only for the windows version.